# How to convert listbox.items to a Array

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a search function for a `ListBox`, and I would like that as soon as the user types something into a `TextBox`, all items are removed from the `ListBox` except the item that matches the search text.

```
//files[i] are the files of the openfiledialog
List<String> ListboxItems = new List<String> {files[i]}; 

try
{
    String search = gunaTextBox1.Text;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListboxItems.ToArray());
    }

    var items = (from a in ListboxItems
                 where a.StartsWith(search)
                 select a).ToArray<String>();

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
}          
catch { }
```

Does anyone know how I can implement this?

Comment: how is this not working -- besides the typos it seems fine.

Comment: i think the problem is that the string should stay outside of a control but then he cant get the files[i]

Comment: Populate the `ListboxItems` list separately, at the same time you originally populate the `ListBox`. Then it will contain the "master list" of items.

Comment: You can simply use the `ListBox.DataSource`. In the `TextChanged` event of `gunaTextBox1`: `listBox1.DataSource = listBoxItems.Where(i => i.IndexOf(gunaTextBox1.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();`. Works as `Contains()`, but case-insensitive. You can change it in `StartsWith()` keeping the same `StringComparison`.

Comment: @RufusL i fixed the problem but i have now a other problem, the text need to match 100%. How can i neglect capitalization? (and i replaced **StartsWith** with **Contains**.

Comment: @Jimi you saved my day. I will try it out

Comment: `where a.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1`

Comment: I thank you guys, very much for helping me. @RufusL

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **solution**

first you need to add a *List String* `List<string> listcollection = new List<string>();`

then you need to write the *Textbox1_TextChanged* event

```
List<string> listcollection = new List<string>();
    private void gunaTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if(gunaTextBox1.Text == "Suche")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                String search = gunaTextBox1.Text;

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    listBox1.Items.AddRange(listcollection.ToArray());
                }

                var items = (from a in listcollection
                             where a.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
                             select a).ToArray<String>();

                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }         
    }
```

and then just link it up

```
 listcollection.Clear();
                foreach(string str in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    listcollection.Add(str);
                }
```